# How to apply jadeify transform before running a mocha test?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mocha.js, browserify, jadeify

I have an app built with **Backbone** and I'm using **Jade** for the templates. I use **Browserify** to build and **jadeify** as a transform to compile the templates to **js** functions.

All of this works great, the problem is when I'm running tests on **Mocha** because the files required are not transformed into js yet.

Anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I ran into the same issue (although I needed rendered HTML). Anyway, in your case, you could use a require hook to [compile](http://jade-lang.com/api/) jade files.

```
// jade-hook.js
import jade from 'jade'

function compile(module, filename) {
  var template = jade.compileFile(filename, { pretty: true })
  module.exports = template
}

if (require.extensions) {
  require.extensions['.jade'] = compile
}
```

And then 
`mocha --require path/to/jade-hook.js`